# How to change value of one cell onchange of other cell value in DataGridview

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

For example: if I'm changing `MRP` column, it should multiply that value with another column value called `No_of_Units` and the result should be stored in column called `Total`, Thanks in advance

Comment: I did CRUD operation in datagridview by searching internet, as i'm new to datagridview i dont know of how to change value of one cell onchange of other cell value, i'm developing billing application in which i need to perform MRP*NO_OF_UNITS=TOTAL(Columns or Cells)

Comment: So, show us what you hav coded in the `CellValueChanged` event and tell us what happens! The normal way is to check for the right `e.ColumnIndex` and then set the respective other cell..

Comment: As i told i'm new to datagridview i know only basic CRUD operstions, i havent done any coding related to my question as i dont know how to start with it no idea, Sorry :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean something like this ?

```
private void DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == index of column MRP)
    {
        int value = (int)DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["NO_OF_UNITS"].Value * (int)DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["MRP"].Value;
        DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["TARGET_COLUMN"].Value = value;
    }
}
```

This answer is simplified, you might need some additional checks, like check on null values and that kind of stuff. But it should get you on your way.

In your comment you asked:

> How to get the index of column MRP ?

Click on the datagrid. Find the property Columns and click on the little button in the list of columns, find the column MRP and copy the Name property. This could be MRP but it also be DataGridColumn1 or something.

Suppose the name property is 'MRP' than you can do:

```
if (e.ColumnIndex == MRP.ColumnIndex)
```

Comment: Yes this what i needed, the code within if block is what i needed, but how to get "index of column MRP", actually i'm doing billing software in which i need to perform such operation.